# Click the button twice to close form in showdialog mode

Tags: c#, showdialog

On main form i've got button and methods:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMyDialogBox();
}

public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   testDialog= new Form3_addrow(tran_in);

   DialogResult dr = testDialog.ShowDialog(this);

   if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
   {
       testDialog.Close();
   }
   else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
   {

       testDialog.Close();
       bool w= kd.dodaj(tran_in);
       if (w) MessageBox.Show("Transakcja dodana");
       else MessageBox.Show("Coś poszło nie tak...");
   }
}
```

and button on Form3_addrow:

```
private void AcptBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    zczytaj();
    this.AcptBtn.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;

}
```

Everything works but i must click twice this button. in debugger mode i saw that first time i click, button handler is called, but nothing more.
Second time, handler is called again and then control returns to ShowMyDialogBox() method.

Comment: The way you should be using a dialog is to make it **close itself** when it's done. You shouldn't close it from outside, but instead just check the dialog result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [what @user3185569 wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21203938/69809):

1. You can set the `Form.CancelButton` and `Form.AcceptButton` properties for your `Form3_addrow` form to point to your `Cancel` and `OK` buttons respectively. In that case you don't even need `Click` event handlers, the form will simply set the `DialogResult` automatically when you click on either of the buttons.
2. You don't have to invoke `Close` on the dialog instance manually, but simply `Dispose` it when you're done.

A usual way to use a modal dialog is through the `using` directive, to ensure that it's disposed immediately after use:

```
using (var addRowForm = new Form3_addrow(tran_in))
{
    var result = testDialog.ShowDialog(this);

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // no need to call Close here
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```

The reason you need to do this is that a modal dialog (i.e. one shown using [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as opposed to just `Show()`) merely hides itself when you close it (or set the `DialogResult` property to a value), to allow you to access its properties even when it's not being shown anymore, as explained on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Replace :

```
this.AcptBtn.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

With

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

the form will close when its DialogResult is set to OK and not that of the button.